# android targetSdkVersion28 update 33 Strange question

Tags: java

Android 28 update 33, users newly install the APP, and the user's avatar can be called up normally to select the picture and complete the avatar upload. However, if the user has previously installed the old version of the app, when the user overwrites and upgrades to the new version of the app, when the user changes the avatar, the message "open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)" is displayed.

When you click on the avatar again, you will be judged and ask for storage permissions, but there is no Permission dialog.

At the time of this error, the following has been done so far

1. `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"`
2. ```xml
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="29"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="32"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO"/>
   ```

Comment: To add: when upgrading from the old version of 28 APP to the new version of 33 APP. The read and write permission of the APP has always been granted from the system settings, and the request permission pop-up window cannot be called up when you click on the avatar.
When installing 33APP directly, the permission to view the start in the settings is not granted, and the subsequent click on the avatar will pop up the permission request window, which can be used normally after granting. It's also normal to view in settings.